# Using the extensions installer (upload package file) is not working all the times

Tags: installation, administration

I was very reserved to post this question, but this is something that I am facing in almost every website, and would like to get feedback from others on this. 
The upload package file in the extensions installer poses an unstable behavior, making the installation a pain.

While trying to install extensions in various server environments, some extensions will be installed without any problem, but for some it won't work right away. It freezes and keep showing the "installation screen" without any progress, if I don't cancel it, it will just stay there forever.

[image: Waiting for minutes the installer...]

There are many cases, where I have to keep re-trying the installation for several times. Then all of sudden, it will complete the installation without any difficulty and without any delay.

I can't find any common clues for when this is happening, it does not happen for any specific extension nor the size of the extension is related.

There are no permission issues, tmp folder location is defined correctly, no FTP settings - and again: at some point it will manage to install the extension in question without any troubles.

This is very annoying and time consuming while building a website and also not the very best for the customers.

Are you also facing this issue? Anyone has any idea what can be the problem here?

Comment: please post an answer if you have on this - I don't :)

Comment: Oh, I was expecting an answer from you within seconds lol. Will take a look through

Comment: Try installing it from the tmp folder as mentioned in my answer from yesterday: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/joomla-tmp-directory-what-is-it-for-and-can-i-delete-its-content/4089#4089 ... Am curious to know the outcome

Comment: From the tmp folder it will work. Also it will work if I keep trying to install from the uploader. But it might take many tries before it happens. The cause of this is what I am trying to figure out...

Comment: Ah - and guess what... This is also happening even in my localhost, so no any weird server restrictions, or upload difficulties.

Comment: Does the server error log (PHP errors, timeouts, memory limits, ...) or the browser console (JS errors) tell anything?

Comment: @Bakual: No nothing like that. I noticed that in many cases, if I purge the expired cache, then it usually is installing it's installing it without troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to think that something might be related to the browser.

I mostly work with Safari 5.1, so I didn't have the chance to extensively test the issue in practice using other browsers.

What I am doing though, is the following:

When the issue appears in Safari, I am clearing the browser's cache, refreshing the page and try again the installation. In many cases, this seems to work and I am able to install the extension.

However there are still a few cases where the installation is not possible. When this is the case, I am using Chrome or Firefox. Installation occurs with no hassle there at the first try.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot but assuming this only happens with large extensions, it **could** be something to so with the max post execution time. In your **php.ini** file, have a look at these 3 lines, and increase the values

```
post_max_size = xxM
upload_max_filesize = xxM
max_execution_time = xxx
```

Comment: +1 for the good thoughts for troubleshooting such issues, but this is not the case for me.

Comment: Hmm ok, and does this only happen with large file sizes or various? I've never had this issue myself before so quite a difficult one. I see in your screenshot you were trying to install `com_jce`, is this one of the extensions that causes problems? If so then I will try myself on different environments

Comment: It can be any extension of any size. There is nothing common among the extensions when this is happening.

Comment: Have you tried with different browsers and operating systems?

Comment: @johnny_s: To be honest I can't report much on this. I should try with different browsers. Currently I mostly use Safari 5.x in Snow Leopard.

Comment: @FFrewin I had a similar issue with Chrome on Ubuntu, so it may be worth giving it a try? At least rule out that possible cause.