# JFolder::create: Could not create directory

Tags: joomla-2.5, permissions

I use Joomla 2.5.4 and I experienced a few days ago, that I cannot upload new extensions, plugins. It has worked perfectly earlier, I haven't modified anything.

```
JFolder::create: Could not create directory Path: /home/users
```

Root directory: `/home/users/45322/web/userpage02`, it is already set on admin panel.
Why should Joomla write to `/home/users/` instead of `/home/users/45322/web/userpage02/*`

Comment: Make sure you `tmp` path is set correctly in the Global Configuration in the Joomla backend

Comment: I'm not sure why it is writing to /home/users/ but the error you are getting can happen when the directory/file permissions are not correct. It might be a good idea to check that these haven't been changed.

Comment: On a shared server, they might have made an update. Sometimes PHP settings change... Asking service provider might be a good step. Also if on the path you gave "45322" (user id?) is wrong it will give the error you mentioned.

Comment: Check your JPATH_SITE value, is it showing your site's root directory path correctly?

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: [joomla.stackexchange.com/a/9470/4042](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/9470/4042)

Answer (score 2):

This is usually a directory permissions issue with the [**tmp folder**](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/joomla-tmp-directory-what-is-it-for-and-can-i-delete-its-content).
When installing extensions, the tmp folder is used by the extensions installer, to extract the uploaded archived file. Therefore, the folder needs to exist and be writable.

A good place to find out if your Joomla folders are writable is by checking in the:

**System Information -> Directory Permissions.**

> - In Joomla 2.5 is under the Site Menu item.
> - in Joomla 3- under the System menu item.

Generally, directory permissions issues can occur either by the actual permissions on a given folder, which can be wrong owner or read/write values, or if a specified directory doesn't exist at all.

For the tmp folder, make sure that there is the correct path folder defined in Joomla Configuration.

In cPanel hosting this usually is something like:

```
"/home/username/tmp"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the owner of Joomla folders to your apache server user.

You can find the apache server user with the following command:

```
ps aux | grep -v root | grep apache | cut -d\  -f1 | sort | uniq
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/125865/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as

For Ubuntu, it's `www-data`.

After you know the apache user name, then you can change the owner of all the folders and files of your Joomla installation. You can use the following command to do so:

(I suppose that your apache user is `www-data`)

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/joomla
```

If you are already inside your Joomla directory, then you can run the following command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
```