# How to create a folder during installation custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, installation

I know how to create a subfolder inside the **media** folder by using `<media folder="media" destination="com_mycom">` in the manifest file. But how to create subfolder inside of the **images** folder during the installation of my custom component for example by using install script? What code do I need to add in the file or inside of `public function install($parent)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put in the header of install script:

```
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
```

and inside of **function install($parent)** put the code:

```
$path = JPATH_SITE . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "images" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "mycom";
$mode = 0755;
JFolder::create($path, $mode);
```

`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` for Joomla 3.x